# How to skip spaces with CustomPaint with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, custom-painting, custom-painter, flutter-custompainter, flutter-custompaint

I'm trying to achive an ARC in flutter, but with "holes" in it.

What I have:
[screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8bqV.png)

What I want:
[achive image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qkK1J.png)

My code:

```
class ProgressArc extends CustomPainter {
 bool isBackground;
  Color progressColor;
  double arcLength;
  ProgressArc({
    Key? key,
    required this.isBackground,
    required this.progressColor,
    required this.arcLength,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 300, 300);
    final startAngle = -math.pi;
    final sweepAngle = arcLength;
    final useCenter = false;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..color = progressColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 20;

    var arc = canvas.drawArc(
      rect,
      startAngle,
      sweepAngle,
      useCenter,
      paint,
    );
    return arc;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Do you guys know what should I do?
I'm trying with CustomPaint, but accepting other approaches
I need this for a chart, chart libraries do not support this chart that i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this can still help you.

Below is the painter class:

```
class ProgressArc extends CustomPainter {
  bool isBackground;
  Color progressColor;
  double arcLength;
  int dynamicPoint;
  double gapSize;

  ProgressArc({
    Key? key,
    required this.isBackground,
    required this.progressColor,
    required this.arcLength,
    required this.dynamicPoint,
    required this.gapSize
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    const rect = Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, 300, 300);
    final double gap = arcLength / 180 * gapSize;
    final double angle = arcLength / dynamicPoint;

    final Paint paint = Paint()
        ..color = progressColor
        ..strokeWidth = 20
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    for (int i = 0; i < dynamicPoint; i++) {
      canvas.drawArc(
        rect,
        -(gap + angle * i), // remove "-" of startAngle and sweepAngle to draw bottom half circle instead of top half
        -(angle - gap * 2),
        false,
        paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

And to use it, I add dynamicPoint for number of dashes, and gapSize, for the gap between 2 dashes:

```
CustomPaint(painter: ProgressArc(
  isBackground: true,
  progressColor: Colors.black,
  arcLength: pi,
  dynamicPoint: 4,
  gapSize: 5.0
))
```